# magento 404 after successful login

Tags: php, magento

I am having a strange problem with my magento installation. I set the admin url to myadmin during installation. In my local.xml file the frontName for admin  is like this:

```
  <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[myadmin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

After sucessful login it redirects to

> > [http://127.0.0.1/index.php/admin/myadmin/index/noRoute/key/53c3c0bf6b77fb838f1d363c24443483/]

and  when i click on dashboard link it works. When i changed  myadmin to admin it works. So is there any solution for this problem ? Any help will be appreciated. 
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem when i had custom admin routing WITH Multi store view as well

I had the issue when i go to http://dev.loc/magento/myadmin/  { i have 404 after login }

But if i used http://dev.loc/magento/storeview/myadmin/ { this works fine }

After debugging this i found that in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php

```
        /**
     * Controller predispatch method
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        .......
        if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
                )));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
            }
            return $this;
        }
```

When you have successful login this IF condition yield false
so this statement that set the redirect after successful login doesn't run

```
$this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
```

So You could extend the Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

and Override the Pre-dispatch function Or You this observer `adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start` to set The redirect Page

```
$this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by rewriting http://dev.loc/magento/myadmin/ {KO}

to http://dev.loc/magento/index.php/admin/myadmin/ {OK}

For nginx:

```
rewrite ^/index.php/admin/myadmin/(.*)$ /index.php/myadmin last;
rewrite ^/myadmin.*$ /index.php/admin/myadmin$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/index.php/myadmin.*$ /index.php/admin/myadmin$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/admin/myadmin.*$ /index.php/admin/myadmin$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Basically, anything coming in on /myadmin, /index.php/myadmin, or /admin/myadmin, gets rewritten to /index.php/admin/myadmin. I'm not sure that first line is actually necessary, it seems redundant, but I didnt test thoroughly. Added the last three lines in the site's nginx config file in location / { ... } and it fixed 404 dashboard error.